# urllib2 does not download pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, download, urllib2

I am using the following code to download my files:

```
def downloadfile(url): #function to download file    
    file_name = filename_parse(url)
    #print "***********************"
    #print "File download started:"
    #stime= time.time()
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    getfilesize(u)
    file_size = getfilesize(u)
    print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s \n" % (file_name, file_size)
    file_size_dl = 0
    block_sz = 512
    progressbar(u,block_sz,file_size_dl,f,file_size)
f.close()
```

the thing is that it can download any file exe, txt and others except .pdf files...how can i make it download the pdfs ?

Comment: What happens when you give it a PDF?

Comment: Yea where does i get stuck? what's the `u.getcode()` and the `u.info()`, also you don' show us how you actually GET the data, `urlopen()` just opens the url.. it doesn't fetch the data (normally via `.read()` or something)

Comment: Use `curl` to make sure your server isn't doing anything unusual when asked for a PDF file.

Comment: Q: Can you download the PDF with a normal bowser?

Comment: Yes pdf can be downloaded using a normal browser. Torxed i will edit the post with the .read()

Comment: well the pdf i checked was http://www.icta.mu/documents/laws/dpa.pdf  but i tried with another pdf and it actually works may be some issue with the server ?

Comment: Most likely they're sending the wrong headers. Check the headers and compare, my guess is that it's some sort of multi-part data header or just bad data-description (content length etc) in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for all of those that stumble upon it and are tyring to download the pdf file using python 2 and urllib2 here is the code:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://mensenhandel.nl/files/pdftest2.pdf'
print "Download started..."
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
with open("test.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)
print "Download completed..."
```

Just modify the URL to your needs...

Source: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/